# Parsing JSON for Swift: SeatGeek API

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm trying to parse JSON from the seat geek API but I keep getting a JSON error. I have tried rearranging the structs but to no avail.

This is what I have now but it is not working. Please help.

import Foundation

class Concerts {

```
struct Returned: Codable {
    let events: [EventsData]
}

struct EventsData: Codable {
    var url: String
    var type: String
    var venue: Location
    var performers: [Performer]
}

struct Performer: Codable {
    var name: String
}

struct Location: Codable {
    var display_location: String!
    var name: String
}



var url = "https://api.seatgeek.com/2/events?venue.state=NY?client_id=\(APIkeys.seatGeekKey)"

var concertArray: [ConcertData] = []
var count = 0

func getData(completed: @escaping () -> ()) {
    let urlString = url
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
        completed()
        return
    }
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        if error != nil {
            print("ERROR")
        }
        do {
            let returned = try JSONDecoder().decode(Returned.self, from: data!)
            
            for data in returned.events {
                self.concertArray.append(ConcertData(venue: data.venue.name, name: data.performers.first?.name ?? "", location: data.venue.display_location, type: data.type, url: data.url ?? ""))
            }
        } catch {
            print("JSON Error")
        }
        completed()
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

}

Comment: can you show the code for `ConcertData`

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine  `code`

struct ConcertData: Codable {
    var venue: String
    var name: String
    var location: String
    var type: String
    var url: String
}

Comment: could you add `print(String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8))` just 
before `if error != nil {...}`, and show us exactly what it prints.
Also use `catch {  print("JSON Error: \(error)") }` and show us the error you get.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Optional("{\"status\":403,\"message\":\"Client is required - visit \\\"https:\\/\\/seatgeek.com\\/account\\/develop\\\"\",\"errors\":[{\"message\":\"Client is required - visit \\\"https:\\/\\/seatgeek.com\\/account\\/develop\\\"\",\"code\":40307}],\"meta\":{\"status\":403}}")
JSON Error: The data couldn’t be read because it is missing.

Comment: the server returns an error about your `client_id`. I get the same error when I use a random `client_id`. So this cannot be decoded into your `Returned` model.

Comment: should your url be:

`https://api.seatgeek.com/2/events?venue.state=NY&client_id=\(APIkeys.seatGeekKey)`

note the "&" before the `client_id`, not "?"

Answer (score 0):

Identified the problem from the comment of @workingdogsupportUkraine

Your API endpoint is not in the correct format, you need to replace `?` with `&` before `client_id` of your URL.

```
var url = "https://api.seatgeek.com/2/events?venue.state=NY&client_id=\(APIkeys.seatGeekKey)"
```

Comment: Have a look at this info. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism and 

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268629/how-do-we-deal-with-plagiarized-answers  and 

https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing

Comment: Thanks, @workingdogsupportUkraine, I thought there needed an answer to be solved, didn't know about the policy before, and I will be more conscious while answering in the future.